# Magento - Find Out of Stock Products With Inventory

Tags: magento

In my Magento store I sometimes forget to select 'In Stock' from the dropdown after adding new inventory to an out of stock item.

Is it possible to somehow get a list of all products which have inventory but as tagged as "Out of Stock"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are able to script something real quick.

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToFilter('is_in_stock', 0)
->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array("gt" => 0));
```

Sadly I can't seem to remember how to put in the >0 in a way that is supposed to work. Maybe someone can comment on that.

What you can do with $products is run it through a foreach loop and then set the is_in_stock to the value of 1 and you should be in business.

Comment: Whoops. I didn't read correctly. This is an awesome code example, thanks Josh

Comment: Replacing the ">0" part with array('gt' => 0) should work, so you end up with ->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array('gt' => 0)).

Comment: A custom script that you create.

Comment: where do you put the custom script?  does it need a name?

Comment: http://overlycaffeinated.com/2011/09/setting-up-your-magento-scripting-environment/ This is an entry from my blog where I describe how I setup Magento scripts.

Comment: Good post, not quite for idiots though 1)an example of the realpath for site.com  I did it once but cant remember what it is.  2)From the command line simply type:  - what command line?  putty? need to be in a directory?  3) so where exactly does the script code go?  Anywhere after Mage::app();?

Comment: 1.) realpath is related to filesystem not your domain (http://us.php.net/realpath) 2.) Yes you will have to run this script from a Terminal window or over SSH 3.) Yes your code will go after Mage::app()

Comment: Got it working - thanks - but the code from this answer gives me an error: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Mage_Eav_Exception' with message 'Invalid attribute name: is_in_stock.' in /home/xxx/public_html/app/Mage.php:536  Thats the right address for mage.php  - any ideas?  thanks.  Also I would add a couple of things to your excellent tut to make it easier for idiots. For example I ran the exact magento_base.php in Putty and the errors told me the realpath!

Comment: Try doing catalog/product_stock instead of catalog/product. I think newer versions force you to use the stock item and not just the product.

Comment: I got the same error.  I found this (now I can run scripts bec of your tut) http://bit.ly/JFGyAT and could run the second script, but I dont know where the output went.  exactly.  But I saw they use addFieldToFilter not addAttributeToFilter & addAttributeToSelect

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way (I think)

Admin -> System -> Import/Export -> Profiles

Add new Profile

Change to export, give the file a name and a location. Download the file and open in your favorite spreadsheet program. Look for "is_in_stock" - 1 = in stock, 0 = out of stock. Filter by 0 and you'll have a list of all of your OOS items.

You can also check the RSS list for low stock alerts at http://shop.com/index.php/rss/catalog/notifystock/

Answer (score 1):

You have to put

> Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty()

code in

> app/design/frontend/default/[yourtemplate]/template/catalog/product/list.phtml

file to check your product inventory.

Answer (score 1):

The shortest way is:

> Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($_collection);

Answer (score 0):

Load Products order by Stock And Descending Order

```
$products
->joinField(
            'inventory_in_stock', 
            'cataloginventory_stock_item', 
            'is_in_stock', 
            'product_id=entity_id',
            'is_in_stock>=0', 
            'left'
)
->setOrder('inventory_in_stock', 'desc');
```